# mantine accordion transition mobile browsers not working

Tags: css-transitions, mantine

I'm using the Mantine Accordion https://mantine.dev/core/accordion/ in my application.
When you open the accordion, there is a transition effect/prop that works on desktop browsers, but not on mobile browsers.

Does anyone have the same problem or a solution?

-webkit does not help, manipulating transition with the prop or sx={{}} doesn't help either

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the solution..

[https://mantine.dev/theming/theme-object/#respectreducemotion[respectreducemotion][1]](https://mantine.dev/theming/theme-object/#respectreducemotion%5Brespectreducemotion%5D%5B1%5D)

just add this to your MantineProvider.
<MantineProvider inherit theme={{ **respectReducedMotion: false** }}>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).